# How to fix ENV related openweather api_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openweathermap

I want to use openweather in my app.

It works good to write directly api_key.
However I introduce ENV, It won't work.

Anyone konws how to fix it?

quesiton is bellow

```
static_pages_controller.rb

...
uri = URI.parse('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tokyo&appid=ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY']')
    json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    res = JSON.parse(json)
    @wind = res['wind']['speed']
    @humidity = res['main']['humidity']
    @clouds = res['clouds']['all']
...
```

```
.env

OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY=20ab....
```

```
error code
/Users/sy/env2/ji-boys/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:19: 
syntax error,
 unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting ')' ...appid=ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY']') ... ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
/Users/sy/env2/ji-boys/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:19: 
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end ...d=ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY']') ... ^
```

I think ...appid=ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY'].. is wrong.
Searching for how to write code, but can't find that.

Anyone knows this, please teach me how to fix it.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do string interpolation to embed value

```rb
URI.parse("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tokyo&appid=#{ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY']}")
```